# Initialize dependent object in simple unidirectional OneToOne mapping

Tags: jpa, mapping, one-to-one

I have a problem with a simple unidirectional mapping. Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Account extends UUIDBase {
    private Profile profile;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Profile extends UUIDBase {
   ...
}
```

Each account must have a Profile assigned. The account should be the owning side of the mapping. Where is the best place to initialize the dependendt Profile attribute? I tried to initialize the profile in the constructor of the Account entity but this doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize it in the constructor, but setting it in the application or a factory may be better.

What does not work, what error do you get?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I think to initialize the reference in a factory is really the better solution. Initialization in the constructor will also work. I just had have an error in my logic.